# automount thumb drive own by root

Tags: automount

I am able to automount my thumb drive on Ubuntu 12.04.4 Server as ordinary user (non-root). However after mounting the owner was root.

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 2048 Jan  1  1970 PP
```

How can change the ownership ?

The automout file  auto.usb was as below.

```
#
# This is an automounter map and it has the following format
# key [ -mount-options-separated-by-comma ] location
# Details may be found in the autofs(5) manpage

#cd     -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev :/dev/cdrom

# the following entries are samples to pique your imagination
#linux      -ro,soft,intr       ftp.example.org:/pub/linux
#boot       -fstype=ext2        :/dev/hda1
#floppy     -fstype=auto        :/dev/fd0
#floppy     -fstype=ext2        :/dev/fd0
#e2floppy   -fstype=ext2        :/dev/fd0
#jaz        -fstype=ext2        :/dev/sdc1
#removable  -fstype=ext2        :/dev/hddA
P -fstype=vfat :/dev/sdi1
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use additional uid and/or gid options, modify number according to your user id:

```
(..)
#removable  -fstype=ext2        :/dev/hddA
P -fstype=vfat :/dev/sdi1 uid=1000,gid=1000
```

See more options for fstab here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

See more automount options here:

http://linuxconfig.org/automatically-mount-usb-external-drive-with-autofs

Comment: Thanks, followed http://linuxconfig.org/automatically-mount-usb-external-drive-with-autofs works!